# Override parent's border when hovering

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` menu inside a `div` `.menu`. The parent `.menu` has a top and bottom `1px solid border`. When hovering over an `li` element another border get added but the parent border still appear above it.

I want to not display the `.menu` top border when hovering over an `li` I don't want to use js unless it's the only solution.

Here is my code and my temporary fix.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fun</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .menu{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    /* I want this border to... ↓ */
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    height:35px;
  }

  .menu ul li{
    display: block;
    float:left;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative;
  }

  .menu ul a{
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
  }

  .menu ul a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: pink;
    /* ...not be displayed above this border when hovering */
    border-top: 3px solid pink;
  }
```

I only found this inefficient solution:

```
.menu ul:hover{
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
```

Codepen link:http://codepen.io/eldev/pen/YPYLQz?editors=110

Any thoughts ?

**Edit:**

backgound-color isn't the same as border-color I made it by mistake. Codepen link updated.

Comment: Currently you cannot target the parent based on a child selector. You will have to use js for this and I suggest you tag the question with it

Comment: I just want to ask why you set a border if it's the same color of the background?

Comment: same question as Daniel...

Comment: Why not just get rid of the top border element? `border-top: 1px solid black;` this one.

Comment: yah sorry I didn't mention that the background of the .menu actually will have an linear-gradient.

Comment: Some like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbdyGg can works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are few solutions at the same time.

like this? (or i don't understand correctly) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJVYMW

i have added `margin-top: -1px` for `ul`

Comment: @elhoucine You should use `position: relative; top: -1px;` and not `margin` because of performance and compatibility issues. `Margin` forces all siblings and children to be recalculated.

Comment: what performance you mean? this margin is used only on first page rendering, not on `:hover` and seems it's very simple page. And anyway same result could be achieved with `position:relative` with `top: -1px` for `ul` without `:hover`

Answer (score 1):

There had to be some modification don't to the CSS; to make it easier to understand, I have added all my changes to the HTML section. I have NOT modified the CSS section.

Here you go http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rapKxE
And the beautified version http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYrXQN

```
< Refer to CodePen >
```

**NOTE** Check the code on codepen for the latest updates.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @elhoucine Hahaha I misunderstood your question. Anyways have a look at the beautified version - maybe you might like it!

Comment: Actually I like it (y).

Answer (score 1):

There are four solutions :

1. `margin-top: -1px;` ;
2. Javascript ;
3. `position: relative; top: -1px;` ;
4. `transform: translateY(-1px)`.

Comment: or `position: relative; top: -1px` or `transform: translateY(-1px)` :)